# Can Civilians own Power Armour?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-2e

Can civilians own Power Armor? I don't see anything exactly prohibiting civilians from owning it (besides cost), but I was curious if I'm missing something.

I know civilians can be armed on a world to world basis, some even have flak jackets and carapace armor.

Comment: It is also important to note that there are untold variants of power armour. Considering only Space Marines there are ten-ish Marks (versions) of power armour, but there are a number of variants of each Mark. Some suits are completely unique encompassing different pieces from different Marks all together. Then there are all the lesser versions used by the Inquision, Sisterhood, etc. It takes a decade or so to build a full Space Marine suit; so say years for smaller versions. But since normal men and women can wear them, with the right amount of influence and money a noble can get one too.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes they can

Civilians can *own* and *use* suits of Power Armor.

However, note that only Space Marines are genetically enhanced with something called [**Black Carapace**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59502/can-a-space-marine-remove-their-armor) (not related to regular "carapace armor")
that allows them to interface with their Power Armor in their unique, second-skin like way. All others (including Adeptus Sororitas and the Inquisition, although they are far from "civilians") use Power Armor as normal enhanced armor. It's still impressive, but only the Space Marines profit from the full potential.

## And they might

Power Armor is hugely expensive, not available for private buyers on the regular market and will surely attract attention from people whose attention normally ends in guilty and innocents dying all the same. The Inquisition and rich Rogue Traders might be able to get hold of suits, but this is nothing that a gang of rich kids might get for their 18th birthday. Well, actually, it just might be if you go back far enough in canon. The [Spyre Hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromunda#Spyre_Hunters), a gang of rich kids from the upper class did just that in the game Necromunda, where gangs fought over territory in the underhive.

## And then...

However, not all "Power Armor" looks like the iconic Space Marine Power Armor Mark I to X. There is Imperial Power Armor, Ex-Imperial (aka Chaos) Power Armor, Tau power armor and probably some other variants. It goes without saying that *anyone* owning a non-Imperial Power Armor *better* be having proof they *killed* the previous owner and are keeping it as a *trophy*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that availability and necessity are also  major factors. Someone living on a hive world likely could never find someone selling power armor unless they are upper-class, or have the money if they did. However, someone living on a forge world could probably find power armor easily enough, but not have use for it, as lighter, cheaper, and much more subtle armor is readily available.

Best-case scenario:

Barring price, the only kind of civilian I imagine owning and using power armor is one living in an underhive, especially the kind that is more warzone than living area.

Comment: Not an answer, because I'm unfamiliar with the system (but I'm familiar with the 40k universe), but are we talking space marine power armor, or something else?  I don't think someone that hasn't gone through all the troubles of becoming a space marine (they're not just baseline humans any more, after all) could even wear power armor.  Besides all the HERESY of someone not blessed with gene-seed wearing it and all.  Owning a set, and being able to wear it effectively are not the same thing, after all.

This could all be moot if the system says otherwise, though.

Comment: @Tal Lighter, human-size power armor exists. Most notably, the upper-class, Inquisitors, and Rogue Traders tend to wear it. Light and Heavy armor are listed in the Core and Enemies Beyond rulebooks.